# Can a dual pole (mechanical) relay switch HVAC and LVDC at the same time?

Tags: relay, safety

As I understand it, a dual pole relay is one which (mechanically) switches two *independent* circuits.

Is it safe to use such a relay (I'm looking at an Omron [MJN2CE](https://datasheet.octopart.com/MJN2CE-DC12-Omron-datasheet-9561612.pdf), specifically) to simultaneously switch 115VAC (i.e. US mains) and 12VDC?

Comment: What barrier or isolation requirements are needed between the two switched circuits?

Comment: @Andyaka, I have no idea? None of it is going to be "exposed to the user", if that's relevant. I would think the answer to that is inherent in the question, however; what such requirements would normally be needed for 115VAC / 12VDC? The 12V side is just some LEDs, fans, and the other end of a PSU, all of which is in the same metal enclosure as all the mains stuff.

Comment: You probably need to resolve that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an extract from Omron MJN2CE datasheet.

[image]

Isolation between 120 V AC and 12 V DC circuits should not be an issue.

Comment: Thanks! IIUC, that means if I had an 800VAC potential from Com to NO of a specific pole, it could potentially arc (and complete a circuit) despite the switch being physically open, correct? But jumping from, say, Com1 to NO2, or between coil and pole, would not happen without much larger voltage?

Comment: Yes, Matthew, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provided that all of the details of the datasheet are met.

This datasheet does not list any minimums, but be aware that most relay contacts will not "whet", "wet", or otherwise make good electrical contact without *some minimum* current flow.  This is usually a small number of milliamps, such as 2 or 5mA.  So as long as this minimum current flows through each contact, it will behave as expected.  Strange things happen below this minimum, where the relay may click closed but not electrically connect the contacts, or contact resistance may change over time.  For this reason, I prefer to test relay contacts with a load of at least 10mA.  Testing with a multimeter is often inconclusive, because the meter is exerting microamps of current or smaller - way below the minimum whetting current.

For the isolation between poles, this is often omitted because it is so high on most relays.  The poles are physically some distance apart, so may have an isolation rating of 2500VAC or more.  Of course specialty relays exist with higher ratings if needed.

Comment: Does that apply to *both* sides, or is, say, driving an LED from the DC side sufficient? (Providing a minimum current on the *AC* side might be "interesting", as I've deliberately designed things to *avoid* switching a "live" AC current under normal operation to avoid arcing, but the DC side is always connected to idiot/safety lights. In theory though I could add some resistors in parallel to provide an always-closed — aside from the relay itself — circuit on the AC side...)

Comment: Whetting current applies to all of the relay's contacts.  This model doesn't have a value listed, but if it were say 2mA, then 2mA must flow through each of the circuits (120VAC and 12VDC) to achieve reliable switching.

Comment: Hold on, I'm confused... are you saying something can *go wrong* if a relay sits around in the "closed" position with no power running through it? (Wouldn't that be equally dangerous to the NO tab when the relay is e.g. just sitting in a box waiting to be installed?) Or is this just a minimum current before *that pole* will pass current reliably, such that e.g. a multimeter connectivity test isn't a reliable way of detecting the relay's state? Put differently, is there anything dangerous about only connecting one pole of a DP relay?

Comment: It's the latter, it's not dangerous.